# Best way to draw tournament bracket in Android

Tags: android, tablelayout, tournament

I need to draw a tournament bracket in Android. I already calculated the positions for all games (i.e. an (x,y) tuple that defines where to place teams in a spreadsheet-like structure). However, I don't know the preferred way of drawing the bracket. I found an example that shows what I need:[Example](http://cdn1.staztic.com/screenshots/comredsulfurpickmybracketfree-7-1.jpg)

My first idea was to programmatically create and fill a `TableLayout`. However, borders are not really supported and a lot of `TextView`s are needed to fill the space between games. So I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Does anyone have better suggestions or maybe even an example of something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest custom drawing using [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). That way you can draw wherever it makes sense and probably even support zooming without too much work.

Comment: This will be my last resort but I hope to reuse some existing widgets.

Comment: I created a subclass of `TextView` and customized the `onDraw` method to support borders. However, I use a `TableView` to arrange them in the bracket. This approach is flexible enough for now and less work than drawing everything on a custom `Canvas`.