# Drawing a tournament bracket in android?

Tags: android, canvas, layout

I have an app that will take a list of players and set them up so that you can go through and create a bracket dynamically. The number of players will change and the names as well.

Instead of showing a whole bracket, my point will be to go in columns. I.e. instead of the left side of the arrow, it show the right side: 
[image: Bracket example]

My questions is how do I best draw this?

My initial thought is to do multiple layouts where I hard code textviews with custom drawables and lines for each column of 16/8/4/2 with just one border, but then I have to constantly change the layout setup.

My second one would be to dynamically draw it on a canvas based on this answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213629/best-way-to-draw-tournament-bracket-in-android), but it didn't give a lot of ideas of implementations.

*My Questions*: If I choose method 1, will I be able to dynamically change the layout of my activity?

If I choose method 2, how could I go about this? I'm still pretty new to android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for question 1, yes you can absolutely change the layout dynamically. You can create several layout files and do one of two things: The first, is you can use your activity's `setContentView(int)` method to completely reset the activity's layout to a new view. The second would be to identify the parent view of the bracket portion, cast it to a `ViewGroup` and use `addView(View)` and `removeView(View)`.

As for question 2, you could go about using a canvas, but it would be quite difficult to use only a canvas, but possibly a combination of a canvas and a set of text views could work. While this isn't directly answering your question, this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/create-a-drawing-app-on-android--cms-704) is one I have used in the past, and gives you an excellent sense of how to work with the Canvas class in android.

Comment: Thanks! I was leaning towards #1 anyway, so I think that's the way I'm going. Since I'm limiting it to 16 people, I might just have a separate layout for each and just refresh for each one or etc.

Comment: Yeah, option 2 is definitely the more difficult option, and you have a lot of other things to worry about like the overhead of a bunch of drawing calls on the canvas and those implications on performance. Anyway, if this does answer your question, don't forget to accept it as the answer!